# Spring Security always return HTTP 403 for POST requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to run an existing Spring Boot 3 application, where I'm finding it hard as Spring Security always returning HTTP 403 for all the requests except for `/health` and `/info`.

Error response :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-11-28T21:31:49.646+00:00",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "path": "/test-service/v1/test"
}
```

pom file :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ActuatorSecurity class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ActuatorSecurityConfig {

  @SuppressWarnings("squid:S2068")
  private static final int BCRYPT_STRENGTH = 16;

  @Value("${metrics_password}")
  private String metricsPassword;

  @Bean
  public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
     BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
     String result = encoder.encode(metricsPassword);
     UserDetails user = User
        .withUsername("actuator")
        .password(result)
        .roles("ACTUATOR_ADMIN")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
  }

  @Bean
  public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCRYPT_STRENGTH);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
metrics_password = password123
```

Does this require to include a Basic Auth authentication header in the request? I find it confusing as GET requests are authenticated without any issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the actuator's endpoints are returning 403, or your question is related to the other endpoints such as /test-service/v1/test?

Comment: `/test-service/v1/test` POST endpoint is returning 403 while actuator endpoints are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this 403 is caused by missing CSRF token. This can be done by adjusting logging level of `CsrfFilter` in `application.yaml`:

```
logging.level:
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter: debug
```

You can also try to disable CSRF protection (not necessarily recommended):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        // ...
        .csrf(c -> c.disable())
```

The recommended soulution would be to include the valid CSRF token in your POST requests.

Comment: its worked when I disabled CSRF protection in `filterChain` method. 
However, adjusting logging level of CsrfFilter in application.properties file didnt work.
Is there more recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Changing the logging is not meant to solve the problem - just confirm that CSRF is the reason of 403. The recommended way is to include valid CSRF token in your POST request. You can disable it permanenetly but only if you're sure it will not expose you to CSRF vulnerability.